# Numerical solution for PDE

Tags: equation-solving, finite-element-method

I have got the help from the expert ''Nasser'' to write the code for the PDE with variable coefficients and mixed boundary conditions define on a square domain:

```
 ClearAll[y, x1, x2];
 a = x1 + x2;
 pde = D[a D[y[x1, x2], x1], x1] + D[a D[y[x1, x2], x2], x2] - 4;
 bc = {y[x1, 2] == 2 + x1, y[x1, 3] == 3 + x1};
 sol = NDSolve[{pde == 
  NeumannValue[-1*a, x2 == 2] + NeumannValue[1*a, x2 == 3], bc}, 
   y, {x1, 2, 3}, {x2, 2, 3}]

  Plot3D[Evaluate[y[x1, x2] /. sol], {x1, 2, 3}, {x2, 2, 3}, 
  PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x1", "X2", "y[x1,x2]"}, 
  BaseStyle -> 12]
```

where  the Neumann BC is define for this problem as a(x)*dy/dn which is equal to a(x)*(grad(y,x1)*n1+grad(y,x2)*n2) which is equal in this probem (as we took the know just to check the accuracy y=x1+x2) =a(x)*(1*n1+1*n2)=a(x)*(n1+n2), we n1,n2 are component of normal vector.

Can we
 1) evalue the numerical values of the solution on the domail?

2) can we evaluate the say relative error between the numerical and the exact which is equal to y=x1+x2?

Best regards

Comment: Towards your questions: 1) You already evaluated the solution many times in `Plot3D` with `y[x1, x2] /. sol` (just insert specific valued of `x1` and `x2`). 2) It should now be self-explaratory that the relative error can be computed with `(1-y[x1, x2] )/(x1+x2)/. sol` (for `x1+x2` nonzero). Bonus: You might also be interest in learning about `NDSolveValue`; it returns an `InterpolationFunction` instead of a `Rule`, so it will save you from calling `ReplaceAll` (`/.`).

Comment: Dear Henrik, many thanks, I have define                                                                                
            x1 = {2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9, 3};

             x2 = {2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9, 3};                                 
             num = Evaluate[y[x1, x2] /. sol]                                                               
             exact = x1 + x2; relerror = (1 - num)/(exact); error?

Comment: Only I could not got the error?

Comment: I solve it by exact = {x1 + x2}, thanks

Comment: Yes, I got the answer, thanks